# How to Pivot a single column source data in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Below are the input and output details.Any database Oracle, SQL Server and MySQL should do for the answers.I am not able to derive the logic to rank data which will help me to pivot.

My source is a flat file which contains data like below.I have loaded that file into one of the tables in Oracle.

Source Input:

```
**Flatfile1**
**Coulmn1**
Kamesh
65
5000
123456789
Nanu
45
3000
321654789
```

Expected Output:

```
Name    Age Salary  Mobilenumber
Kamesh  65  5000    123456789
Nanu    45  3000    321654789
```

After loading into one of the tables I am applying the logic to number this data which will eventually look like below:

```
Column1 Datavalue
Kamesh      1
65          1
5000        1
123456789   1
Nanu        2
45          2
3000        2
321654789   2
```

However, I am not able to derive logic (I tried with Rank) which will give me sequence number like this without having any key field.Hope this explains situation.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you really have all the information stored in one column like that?

Comment: Show us what you tried already.

Comment: (1) SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.  (2) You don't identify which values correspond to which columns.  (3) You should tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Yes we do have that file like this.

Comment: @J.Chomel: Updated the question

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Tagged Oracle.There is no identifier and given the source, it is mandated that rows will be coming in this order.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't store the rows in order, if you do select * from table1 multiple times you could get rows in different orders according to db operations and caching

Therefore if you have a table like that with no other column it's impossible to "pivot" the data. 
I strongly suggest to save data in a normalized form, if you can't consider adding a column with a row ID populated automatically (identity column in oracle 12, trigger+ sequence in previous version)

Once you have your rows in order it will be easy to organize your data

Comment: I tried with Row_ID.It seems to be generating the sequence number.I am not able to connect how it will help me to pivot data?